# Android NDK pulling in JNI stuff with gradle and jitpack?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

I have an android library project on github. Its basically the java port of the popular BASS library: http://www.un4seen.com/

All the .so files are in a directory `/jniLibs` found in `src/main`.

I can make a release and am able to grab it using jitpack. I know its working because I have a test class in the library and I can see it in autocomplete after adding the library to my project via gradle.

Though that class works, I can seem to use any of the BASS methods. Why would this be?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently when using the ndk you need to be careful of package names.

It was undocumented, but for my case, the BASS library on needed to have a specific package name to be accessed. In this case it was `com.un4seen.bass`